# Firebase - Filterable - Search View

Tags: android, firebase, app, filter

Estou desenvolvendo um app, uso o Firebase como banco de dados para armazenar os clientes cadastrados. Assim tenho uma ListView que mostra esses clientes, mostra o nome e o CPF deles. O que estou precisando fazer é uma pesquisa, que coloque o nome ou cpf e encontra a pessoa mais fácil. Tentei fazer de várias formas, vi que da pra fazer usando Filterable, mas não entendi como funciona isso, não estou conseguindo carregar as funções. Melhor usar o ListView mesmo? tenho que usar o Search View?

Obrigadooo

Comment: Sim, tem que usar searchview junto com a recyclerview, fica beeem mais fácil. Dá uma olhada nesse link que vai ensinar bem certinho https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/03/searchview-with-recyclerview.html. A fonte de dados do adapter não importa blz, serve pra listas simples quanto pra listas complexas.

Comment: Posta seu codigo amigo, assim podemos te ajudar com mais facilidade.